# Validar input - solo letras y espacios con PHP

Tags: php, input

Estoy intentando validar un input con php, pero tengo algunos problemas y es que quiero que reuna las siguientes condiciones:

1. Que solo acepte letras y espacios (mayusculas, minusculas y
   caracteres como ñ, tildes...)
2. Que no acepte caracteres (tipo $#@%, signos de puntuación, etc)
3. Que no acepte números

**Lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente forma:**

```
function valnombre($nombre) {
    $patron = "/^[a-zA-Z\d]*$/";
    if(preg_match($patron, $nombre)) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Luego intento validar asi:**

```
if (valnombre($nombre)=="") {
  echo("<p>Debe introducir su nombre</p>");
}...
```

**He probado con:**

```
$patron = "/^[a-zA-Z\d]*$/";
$patron ="/^[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÜüñÑ]/";
introducir el código aquí
```

El punto es que siempre se imprime el `echo`, o si pasa se imprimen caracteres que no deseo, no se mucho de `preg_match()`, he leigo un poco pero aún estoy algo confundido, así que preferí pedir ayuda a los expertos.

gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
    function isValid($text){
        $pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z\sñáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]+$/";
        return preg_match($pattern, $text);
    }
    
    $first_example = "Hola ñandú";
    $second_example = "Un paj4ro";
    $third_example = "cesar@cesar.cl";
    
    echo isValid($first_example) ? ' valid ' : ' invalid '; 
    echo isValid($second_example) ? ' valid ' : ' invalid '; 
    echo isValid($third_example) ? ' valid ' : ' invalid ';
```

La salida será : `valid  invalid  invalid`

**Revisemos la expresión regular en detalle:**

`/` = Delimitador de la expresión regular, define el inicio y el fin.

`[]` = Definición de una clase, el carácter puede ser cualquiera de los valores que se encuentran definidos dentro de la clase.

`a-z` = Rango de letras desde la a hasta la z, seria lo mismo que escribir `abcdefg...`

`A-Z` = Rango de letras desde la A hasta la Z, lo mismo que antes pero en mayusculas

`\s` = El equivalente a un carácter de tipo espacio

`ñáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ` = caracteres que no están incluidos en a-z y A-Z, para que la expresión coincida cuando estén estos caracteres.

`^` = Define que la expresión debe aplicar desde el comienzo de la cadena

`$` = Define que la expresión debe aplicar hasta el final de la cadena

`+` = repetirá la clase de caracteres para buscar coincidencias UNA o más veces, si quieres considerar cadenas vacías como validas puedes cambiar el + por un *.

La expresión regular será valida con solo un espacio en blanco, si quieres evitar eso, asegúrate de hacer un trim al valor antes de validarlo con la expresión regular.

```
    function isValid($text){
        $pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z\sñáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]+$/";
        return preg_match($pattern, trim($text));
    }
```

Si quieres que el texto tenga un mínimo de caracteres procura remplazar el cuantificador `+` por `{x,y}`, donde x es el mínimo de coincidencias e y el máximo, si y o x están vacíos, será N (infinita) veces.

Ej: Esto requiere de una cadena de al menos 5 caracteres.

```
    function isValid($text){
        $pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z\sñáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]{5,}$/";
        return preg_match($pattern, $text);
    }
```